# Simple reusable javascript averaging function for multiple forms on same page

Tags: javascript, average

I literally started trying to teach myself javascript less than 48 hours ago.  Outside of just wanting to learn it I also have a small personal project I'm working on and using as sort of my working learn as I go example.  But I've hit a problem, which I'm sure is rather basic, I'm just hampered by lack of much javascript knowledge.

Basically it is just an averaging problem.
There are going to be 4 inputs fields with the 4th being a rounded to the nearest whole number average of the first three fields.
This 4 field configuration is going to get used multiple times on the page.
I want it to work in "real time" and not with a calculate button so I'm assuming "**onKeyup**" is needed. (no validation of any kind is needed or submit or saving or anything)

The only code I've been able to get close is really really ugly, long, and convoluted. I can't help but think there is a very simple way to do it and just get the same function to apply to each grouping of inputs. It will look like below but probably much longer.

```
some text
<input id="a" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="b" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="c" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="final" value="0" disabled />

some text
<input id="a" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="b" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="c" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="final" value="0" disabled />
```

Thanks in advance.  This is part of a larger problem but I've tried to strip it down to it's essence and seeing it work and understanding it will go a long way to helping me solve some other problems.

Answer (score 1):

To start with use a different markup, there should only be a single id per page, so use classes, it make it easier to target everything too. Also if the effect is to use the last input as a display you can use readonly instead of disabled

```
<p>some text</p>
<div class="group">
    <input class="a" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="b" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="c" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="final" value="0" readonly />
</div>
<p>some text</p>
<div class="group">
    <input class="a" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="b" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="c" type="number" /><br/>
    <input class="final" value="0" readonly />
</div>​
```

Here is an example done in jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.group input').on('click', function() {
        var count = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        $(this).siblings(':not(.final)').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()) count = count + parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $(this).siblings('.final').eq(0).val(count);
    });
});
```

And the demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4S4Vp/1/
​

Answer (score 1):

This should be understandable for your level. The second set of inputs will be named a-2 with calc(2) and so on.

```
<input id="a-1" type="number" onkeyup="calc(1)" value="0" /><br/>
<input id="b-1" type="number" onkeyup="calc(1)" value="0" /><br/>
<input id="c-1" type="number" onkeyup="calc(1)" value="0" /><br/>
<input id="final-1" value="0" disabled />

function calc( n ) {
    var a = document.getElementById("a-" + n ).value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b-" + n ).value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c-" + n ).value;
    document.getElementById("final-" + n ).value = Math.round((parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)+parseInt(c))/3);
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Much nicer looking than the mess I made. And the light bulb came on a bit brighter.

thank you everyone else as well. it has all helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

This is really quick and dirty, but if you know how many inputs you have, this should work:

```
// these would instead be your textboxes
​var a = document.getElementById('a').value();
var b = document.getElementById('b').value();
var c = document.getElementById('c').value();

var avg = (a+b+b)/3;

document.getElementById('c').value() = avg;
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCU3S/) so you can play with the idea and see if it works as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

see the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a875A/7/) on jsfiddle

```
some text
<div id="div1">
<input id="a" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="b" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="c" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="final" value="0" disabled />
</div>
some text
<div id="div2">
<input id="a" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="b" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="c" type="number" /><br/>
<input id="final" value="0" disabled />
</div>​

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#div1 input").bind('change keyup click',function(){
    var final = 0;
    $("#div1 input").not("#div1 #final").each(function(idx,el){
        final += (el.value) ? parseInt(el.value) : 0;
    });
    $("#div1 #final").val(final/3);
});
$("#div2 input").bind('change keyup click',function(){
    var final = 0;
    $("#div2 input").not("#div2 #final").each(function(idx,el){
        final += (el.value) ? parseInt(el.value) : 0;
    });
    $("#div2 #final").val(final/3);
});
​</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hoped to flag this as duplicate, but because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050781/mapreduce-how-do-i-calculate-relative-values-average-top-k-and-so) does not have code, enjoy:

```
// find all inputs in the page and gather data trying to convert it to number
var data = [].map.call( document.querySelectorAll('input'), function (v) {
    if (typeof v.value * 1 === 'NaN') {
        return 'NaN';
    }
    return v.value * 1;         
});
// not all data will be valid, so we filter it
data = data.filter( function (v) {
   return !isNaN(v);
});
// and then calculate average
var avg = data.reduce( function (v, v1) {
    return v + v1;
}) / data.length;
```